# How to fix System.ApplicationException with regards to GSM c# on visual studio?

Tags: c#, gsm

I'm creating an SMS application on Visual c# and i dunno what error i'm getting since i tried the same code on CodeProject using AT commands for GSM

the SIM card i have has just 1 message, i downloaded the sample code from codeproject it works just fine, then i copied the class source codes tried to make a new application, when i tried to get the number of messages inside the SIM it says:

> System.ApplicationException response received is incomplete

here is the code for counting message inside SIM:

```
public int CountSMSmessages(SerialPort port)
        {
            int CountTotalMessages = 0;
            try
            {

                #region Execute Command

                string recievedData = ExecCommand(port, "AT", 300, "No phone connected at ");
                recievedData = ExecCommand(port, "AT+CMGF=1", 300, "Failed to set message format.");
                String command = "AT+CPMS?";
                recievedData = ExecCommand(port, command, 1000, "Failed to count SMS message");
                int uReceivedDataLength = recievedData.Length;

                #endregion

                #region If command is executed successfully
                if ((recievedData.Length >= 45) && (recievedData.StartsWith("AT+CPMS?")))
                {

                    #region Parsing SMS
                    string[] strSplit = recievedData.Split(',');
                    string strMessageStorageArea1 = strSplit[0];     //SM
                    string strMessageExist1 = strSplit[1];           //Msgs exist in SM
                    #endregion

                    #region Count Total Number of SMS In SIM
                    CountTotalMessages = Convert.ToInt32(strMessageExist1);
                    #endregion

                }
                #endregion

                #region If command is not executed successfully
                else if (recievedData.Contains("ERROR"))
                {

                    #region Error in Counting total number of SMS
                    string recievedError = recievedData;
                    recievedError = recievedError.Trim();
                    recievedData = "Following error occured while counting the message" + recievedError;
                    #endregion

                }
                #endregion

                return CountTotalMessages;

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }

        }
```

and here is my form:

```
private void Login_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.port = sms.OpenPort();
            if (sms.OpenPort().IsOpen)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("CONNECTED TO GSM");
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("NOT CONNECTED TO GSM");
            }

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int count = sms.CountSMSmessages(this.port);
            if (count > 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("INBOX NOT EMPTY");
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("INBOX EMPTY");
            }   
        }
```

somehow im getting error on `sms.CountSMSMessages` function
my GSM connects fine, i even tested it on the sample code and i read the message inside the sim. i dunno what im doing wrong, someone please help

any help is greatly appreciated thanks

EDITED:
here is the ExecCommand code

```
public string ExecCommand(SerialPort port, string command, int responseTimeout, string errorMessage)
        {
            try
            {

                port.DiscardOutBuffer();
                port.DiscardInBuffer();
                receiveNow.Reset();
                port.Write(command + "\r");

                string input = ReadResponse(port, responseTimeout);
                if ((input.Length == 0) || ((!input.EndsWith("\r\n> ")) && (!input.EndsWith("\r\nOK\r\n"))))
                    throw new ApplicationException("No success message was received.");
                return input;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }
```

i just followed the codes from a working sample in CodeProject, then tried to display message count in inbox and i get errors,

Comment: Where is the "ExecCommand"?  You have a communication system where you application is the master (client) and the SIM card is the slave (server).  So the master sends commands and the slave returns responses.  The ExecCommand sends the commands to the SIM device and you did not send any commands, just tried to read a response.  So eventually the method timed out because the device did not send a response.

Comment: edited, if i understand it correctly, i just passed the port parameter because in the countsms function the parameters for ExecCommand is already set, and at ExecCommand function sends the command passed from countsms, but i dunno where the error lies,

Comment: Put a break point after you read the input.  Then check if the command is correct and check what message you actually receive.  Compare against working code.